# Validate phone number without country code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app my users can enter their phone number.

I'm using [phonelib](https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib) to validate phone numbers, however my service will only be available in one country so I don't want my users to enter the country code every time they enter their phone number to the server.

I tried to configure my `phonelib.rb` like so:

```
Phonelib.default_country = "CHE"
```

but still it gives me phone invalid if I don't enter the `+41` country code when I try to enter a phone number.

Is it possible to do it throw [phonelib](https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib) or is other solutions better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a "future proof" standpoint I would still advise on keeping the country codes there.

You could have the country code showing up by default on all phone fields so users don't have to type it if there's only one country code, but that way you'd be making sure your data quality.

Anyway, just my 2 cents..

Comment: The problem is that I'm also developing an API and I'm not responsible for the development on the android part. So I want a solution that I could validate on my side without having to bother the android development guys :p

Comment: That's cool - if you're building an API you could set it so that on your end you have a country code field that by default is set to that country unless a different one is specified. That way, if later on the Android guys decide to add a country code, your API already supports it natively and all your data is consistent without any changes required.

Comment: Haha, so reparei no nome agora, portuguesa certo? :) Boa sorte pra API! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just capture any phone number regardless but have a custom validator for that uses `Phonelib`.

This here validates the input and tells the user what it expects.

#### app/models/model_name.rb

`validates_with PhoneCountryCodeValidator, fields: [:client_mobile], country_codes: ["CH", :ch, Phonelib.default_country]`

#### app/models/concerns/phone_country_code_validator.rb

```
class PhoneCountryCodeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    options[:fields].any? do |field|
      phone_number = record.send(field)
      phone_country = Phonelib.parse(phone_number).country
      phone_country_code = phone_country.to_s.upcase

      options[:country_codes].any? do |valid_country|
        valid_country_code = valid_country.to_s.upcase
        unless phone_country_code == valid_country_code
          record.errors.add(field, "has an invalid country code:
            #{phone_country_code} should be #{valid_country_code}")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also checkout this issue for more details: https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib/issues/136